# Angular unit test function with window.loocation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a service with a function like this:

```
public logout(): any {
    this._cookie.removeAll(this.cookieOption);
    return window.location.href = '/';
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I run the tests, it never runs properly, because when I call this function the browser keeps refreshing and re-running all the tests again.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you used [the `Location` service](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) via DI, you could easily mock it out with the `TestBed`.

Comment: I have created this code, check this out, [mocking in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090244/understanding-angulars-fakebackendprovider-mockbackend-and-mockconnection/47090537#47090537)

Comment: @jonrsharpe would you mind elaborating an answer?